# How to get number of invoices for last 12 weeks in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-3, aggregate-functions, generate-series

Invoice database contains invoice dates:

```
create table dok (
  dokumnr serial primary key,
  invoicedate date not null
);
```

Dashboard requires comma separated list containing number of invoices for last 12 weeks, e.q

4,8,0,6,7,6,0,6,0,4,5,6

List contains always 12 elements. If there are no invoices for some 7 day interval, 0 should appear.
Every element should contain number of invoices for 7 days.

Query should find maximum date before current date:

```
select max(invoicedate) as last_date from dok;
```

And after that probably use count(*) and string_agg() to create list.

Last (12th) element should contain number of invoices for

```
  last_date .. last_date-interval'6days'
```

11 element (one before last) should contain number of invoices for days

```
  last_date-interval'7days' .. last_date-interval'14days'
```

etc.

How to write this query in Postgres 9.1+ ?
This is ASP.NET MVC3 C# application and some parts of query can also done in C# code if this helps.

I ended with

```
with list as (

SELECT count(d.invoicedate) as cnt
   FROM  (
      SELECT max(invoicedate) AS last_date
      FROM   dok
      WHERE   invoicedate< current_date
      ) l
   CROSS  JOIN generate_series(0, 11*7, 7) AS g(days)
   LEFT   JOIN dok d ON d.invoicedate>  l.last_date - g.days - 7
                    AND d.invoicedate<= l.last_date - g.days
   GROUP  BY g.days
   ORDER  BY g.days desc
)

SELECT string_agg( cnt::text,',')
from list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` the latest date to `generate_series()`, followed by a `LEFT JOIN` to the main table.

```
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT count(d.invoicedate) AS ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT max(invoicedate) AS last_date
      FROM   dok
      WHERE  invoicedate < current_date  -- "maximum date before current date"
      ) l
   CROSS  JOIN generate_series(0, 11*7, 7) AS g(days)
   LEFT   JOIN dok d ON d.invoicedate >  l.last_date - g.days - 7
                    AND d.invoicedate <= l.last_date - g.days
   GROUP  BY g.days
   ORDER  BY g.days
   );
```

Assuming there is at least one valid entry in the table,
this returns an array of bigint (`bigint[]`) with the latest week *first*.

`current_date` depends on the `timezone` setting of your session.

If you need the result to be a comma-separated string you could use another query layer with `string_agg()` instead. Or you feed the above to `array_to_string()`:

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT ...), ',');
```

#### Your query audited:

It's an implementation detail, [but it's documented:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

> The aggregate functions `array_agg`, `json_agg`, `jsonb_agg`,
>   `json_object_agg`, `jsonb_object_agg`, `string_agg`, and `xmlagg`, as
>   well as similar user-defined aggregate functions, produce meaningfully
>   different result values depending on the order of the input values.
>   This ordering is unspecified by default, but can be controlled by
>   writing an `ORDER BY` clause within the aggregate call, as shown in
>   [Section 4.2.7](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). **Alternatively, supplying the input values from a
>   sorted subquery will usually work.** For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT xmlagg(x) FROM (SELECT x FROM test ORDER BY y DESC) AS tab;
> ```
>
> Beware that this approach can fail if the outer query level contains
>   additional processing, such as a join, because that might cause the
>   subquery's output to be reordered before the aggregate is computed.

Bold emphasis mine.
To stay standard compliant, you could write:

```
WITH list AS (
   SELECT g.days, count(d.invoicedate)::text AS cnt
   FROM  (
      SELECT max(invoicedate) AS last_date
      FROM   dok
      WHERE  invoicedate < current_date
      ) l
   CROSS  JOIN generate_series(0, 11*7, 7) AS g(days)
   LEFT   JOIN dok d ON d.invoicedate >  l.last_date - g.days - 7
                    AND d.invoicedate <= l.last_date - g.days
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT string_agg(cnt, ',' ORDER BY days DESC)
FROM   list;
```

But this is a bit slower. Also, the CTE is *not technically necessary* and also a bit slower than a subquery.
`SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT ...), ',')` like I proposed is fastest because the array constructor is faster for a single result than the aggregate function `string_agg()`.

Comment: Thank you. I ended with query in updated part of question. Is this OK? Will it return latest week last ?

Comment: @Andrus: Yes, it will. Consider the addendum to my answer.