# Filter jsonb results in subselect

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-json

I'm building a hierarchical JSON result from several tables. These are just examples but should be sufficient for the purpose of this demonstration to get the idea:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    data JSONB
);
CREATE TABLE author (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    data JSONB
);
CREATE TABLE book_author (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    author_id INTEGER,
    book_id INTEGER
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_unique ON book_author (author_id, book_id);
```

Test data:

```
INSERT INTO book (id, data) VALUES
  (1, '{"pages": 432, "title": "2001: A Space Odyssey"}')
, (2, '{"pages": 300, "title": "The City And The City"}')
, (3, '{"pages": 143, "title": "Unknown Book"}');

INSERT INTO author (id, data) VALUES
  (1, '{"age": 90, "name": "Arthur C. Clarke"}')
, (2, '{"age": 43, "name": "China Miéville"}');

INSERT INTO book_author (id, author_id, book_id) VALUES
  (1, 1, 1)
, (2, 1, 2);
```

I've created the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.book_get()
  RETURNS json AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    result json;
BEGIN
      SELECT to_json(array_agg(_b)) INTO result
      FROM (
        SELECT
          book.id id,
          book.data->>'title' title,
          book.data->>'pages' pages,
          (
            SELECT to_json(array_agg(_a))
            FROM (
              SELECT
                author.id id,
                author.data->>'name' "name",
                author.data->>'age' age
              FROM
                author, book_author ba
              WHERE
                ba.author_id = author.id AND 
                  ba.book_id = book.id
              ORDER BY id
            ) _a
          ) authors
        FROM
          book
        ORDER BY id ASC
      ) _b;
        
    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Executing the function `book_get`

```
SELECT book_get();
```

Produces the following results

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"2001: A Space Odyssey",
      "pages":432,
      "authors":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Arthur C. Clarke",
            "age":90
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"The City And The City",
      "pages":300,
      "authors":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"China Miéville",
            "age":43
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Unknown Book",
      "pages":143,
      "authors":null
   }
]
```

Now I'm able to filter the data with a `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT to_json(array_agg(_b)) INTO result
FROM (
 ...
) _b
-- give me the book with id 1
WHERE _b.id = 1;
-- or give me all titles with the occurrence of 'City' anywhere
WHERE _b.title LIKE '%City%';
-- or has more than 200 pages
WHERE _b.pages > 200;
```

How would I make it possible to filter on `authors`? E.g. something equivalent to `WHERE _b.authors.'name' = 'Arthur C. Clarke'`.

I have absolutely no idea what type `authors` becomes? Or is? Is it still a record (array)? Is it JSON already? I guess because I can access `id`, `title` and `pages` accessing `_b.authors` isn't such a problem?

Accessing `_b.authors` gives me `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "authors"`

Accessing with JSON operators `_b.authors->>..` or `_b->authors->>..` gives me

> ```
> operator does not exist: record -> json
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

I remember using `GROUP BY` with the `HAVING` clause:

```
GROUP BY _b.authors
HAVING _b.authors->>'name' = 'Arthur C. Clarke';
```

But it gives me the error:

> ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json

To make it a bit more clear:

```
      SELECT to_json(array_agg(_b)) INTO result
      FROM (
        ...
      ) _b
      WHERE _b.authors->0->>'name' = 'Arthur C. Clarke';
```

Will basically do what I need, this only matches if the author on index `0` is `Arthur C. Clarke`. If he has cowritten the book and he would be on second place (index 1) then there wouldn't have been a match. So what I try to find is the correct syntax on scanning `_b.authors` which happens to be an JSON array filled with authors. It just doesn't accept any attempt. As far as I understand are the `@>` and `#>` only supported for `JSONB`. So how do I get the correct syntax on selecting `_b.authors` on any column against a value.

#### Update 2

Ok read the docs again ... it seems I didn't get the part from Postgres documentation that there is a difference between JSON and JSONB regarding functions, I thought it was only concerning the data type. Replacing `to_json` with `to_jsonb` seems to do the trick with using operators like `@>` etc in the where clause.

#### Update 3

@ErwinBrandstetter: Makes sense. LATERAL wasn't known to me yet, good to know it exists. I got the hang on JSON/JSONB's functions and operators, makes a lot of sense to me now. What isn't clear to me is finding occurrences with `LIKE` for example in the `WHERE` clause.

If I need to use `jsonb_array_elements` to unnest objects in an array (because in the final `WHERE` clause, the content of `b.authors` is of JSONB datatype). I could then do

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements('[
  {"age": 90, "name": "the Arthur C. Clarke"},
  {"age": 43, "name": "China Miéville"},
  {"age": null, "name": "Erwin the Brandstetter"}
]'::jsonb) author
WHERE 
  author->>'name' LIKE '%the%';
```

and get the desired result,

```
1: {"age": 90, "name": "the Arthur C. Clarke"}
2: {"age": null, "name": "Erwin the Brandstetter"}
```

but whats the approach to achieve this in the final (last) `WHERE` clause in my example? Pointing out the final `WHERE` clause because I'd like to filter the complete set of results, and not partially filter somewhere in the middle of a sub-select. So in general I would like to filter out books in the final result set that have an author with a middle name 'C.' or a first name 'Arthur'.

#### Update 4

In the `FROM` clause of course. I'll have to do performance tweaking at the end when I figured out all possibilities, but this is what I came up with.

```
SELECT json_agg(_b) INTO result
FROM (
...
) _b,
jsonb_array_elements(_b.authors) AS arrauthors
WHERE arrauthors->>'name' LIKE 'Arthur %';
```

Will give all books with an author name starting with 'Arthur'. I still appreciate comments or updates to this approach.

Comment: Do you need to return the complete `data` column (all keys) or a selection from it. Your example does not make that clear.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Basically the complete `date`, but not nested in the key `data`, they should be on the "root" level

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter and you should write a book, seriously. Almost every question I land on, you give detailed answers from different perspectives. Something like a cookbook or best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I make it possible to filter on authors? E.g. something
> equivalent to `WHERE _b.authors.'name' = 'Arthur C. Clarke'`.

You are on the right track in your question updates with `jsonb` and the "contains" operator `@>`. The best approach depends on what and how you want to filter *exactly*.

### Basic function

Your basic function can be simpler:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.book_get()
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT jsonb_agg(books)
FROM  (
   SELECT b.data || jsonb_build_object('id', b.id, 'authors', a.authors) AS books
   FROM   book b
   LEFT   JOIN (  -- LEFT JOIN to include books without authors
      SELECT book_id, jsonb_agg(data_plus) AS authors
      FROM  (
         SELECT ba.book_id, jsonb_set(a.data, '{id}', to_jsonb(a.id)) AS data_plus
         FROM   book_author ba
         JOIN   author a ON a.id = ba.author_id
         ORDER  BY ba.book_id, ba.author_id
         ) a0
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) a ON a.book_id = b.id
   ORDER  BY b.id
   ) b0
$func$;
```

#### Major points

- Make it SQL, simpler. No need for plpgsql.
- Make it [`STABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html).
- Don't omit the keyword `AS` for *column* aliases.
- Use [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

If you just want to add the `id` column as key to your `data`, there are simpler ways:

1. With the new **[`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)** in Postgres **9.5**:

   ```
        jsonb_set(data, '{id}', to_jsonb(id))
   ```

   This adds the object or updates the value of an existing object with the same key - the equivalent of an UPSERT in SQL. You can also constrain the operation to UPDATE *only*, see the manual.
   I use this in the inner subquery to add a *single* key.
2. [Concatenate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) two `jsonb` values:

   ```
        b.data || jsonb_build_object('id', b.id, 'authors', a.authors)
   ```

Again, existing keys on the same level in the left value are replaced with keys in the right value. I build the object with `jsonb_build_object()`. See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)

I use this in the outer subquery, simpler to add *multiple* keys. (And to demonstrate both options.

Your original query converted all values to `text`, which is probably not intended. This query preserves original data types for all `jsonb` values.

### Test result

To **test the result** of your function for the existence of the author:

```
SELECT public.book_get() @> '[{"authors": [{"name":"Arthur C. Clarke"}]}]';
```

You have match the JSON structure in the pattern. And it only works for an ***exact match***.
Or you can use `jsonb_array_elements()` like you added in your last update for partial matches.

Either method is ***expensive*** since you test *after* building a JSON document from three whole tables.

### Filter first

To **actually filter** books that have (possibly among others!) the given author, adapt your underlying query. You ask to filter books that ...

> have an author with a middle name 'C.' or a first name 'Arthur'.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(b.data || jsonb_build_object('id', b.id, 'authors', a.authors) ORDER BY b.id) AS books
FROM   book b
     , LATERAL (  -- CROSS JOIN since we filter before the join
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(a.data, '{id}', to_jsonb(a.id)) ORDER BY a.id) AS authors
   FROM   book_author ba 
   JOIN   author a ON a.id = ba.author_id
   WHERE  ba.book_id = b.id
   ) a
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1                                 -- one of the authors matches
   FROM   book_author ba
   JOIN   author a ON a.id = ba.author_id
   WHERE  ba.book_id = b.id
   AND   (a.data->>'name' LIKE '% C. %' OR  -- middle name 'C.'
          a.data->>'name' LIKE 'Arthur %')  -- or a first name 'Arthur'.
   );
```

Filter books that have at least one matching author *before* you build the result.

Note how I use `ORDER BY` as modifier to the `jsob_agg()` aggregate function instead of a subquery to sort results like in the previous example. This is typically *slower* but shorter. And good enough for a small result set. Consider:

- [Joining arrays within group by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557344/postgresql-joining-arrays-within-group-by-clause/24560018#24560018)
- [How to get number of invoices for last 12 weeks in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902777/how-to-get-number-of-invoices-for-last-12-weeks-in-postgres/30903357#30903357)

If your tables are big and you need the queries fast, use **indexes**! For this particular query a function trigram GIN index like this should work wonders for big tables:

```
CREATE INDEX author_special_idx ON author USING gin ((data->>'name') gin_trgm_ops);
```

Detailed explanation / instructions:

- [Pattern matching on jsonb key/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939560/pattern-matching-on-jsonb-key-value/32959762#32959762)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

Comment: A got it ;) Updated my answer with a final 3 about similarities.. :D

Comment: @dbf: You already accepted but I think I have a better answer yet. Consider the update.

Comment: Hmm k, `LATERAL` for `b` to be available in the cross-join with `book_authors` and `author`, [EXISTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html) to evaluate each `ROW` and not the complete result-set (as in my example) .. right? That the queries might be expensive is for now not a concern to me. I develop with performance and quality in mind, but the setup I'm building is bit to complicated to explain in a comment .. don't forget to think about writing a book :)

Comment: @dbf: For big tables indexes are *essential*, and the predicates must be *sargable* and match existing indexes. For small tables, the simplest solution is good enough. I'll think about the book. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A nice [tutorial on JSOn in postgresql](http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/) is recommended. If you create your data in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE json_test (
  id serial primary key,
  data jsonb
);
INSERT INTO json_test (data) VALUES 
  ('{"id":1,"title":"2001: A Space Odyssey","pages":432,"authors":[{"id":1,"fullname":"Arthur C. Clarke"}]}'),
  ('{"id":2,"title":"The City And The City","pages":300,"authors":[{"id":2,"fullname":"China Miéville"}]}'),
  ('{"id":3,"title":"Unknown Book","pages":143,"authors":null}');
```

You can select with a specific id

```
SELECT * FROM json_test
WHERE data @> '{"id":2}';
```

Or look for a specific name in a sub-array:

```
SELECT * FROM json_test
WHERE data -> 'authors' @> '[{"fullname": "Arthur C. Clarke"}]'
```

Or find book with over 200 pages:

```
SELECT * FROM json_test
WHERE (data -> 'pages')::text::int > 200
```

Comment: Though, reading your answer gave me the idea to read the docs again about `JSONB` and `JSON`. It isn't very probable to assume that I can just `change my data this way`, the data is and remains relational according to there keys, dumping everything in a JSONB field isn't a solution I'm looking for.